# Is there an equivalent of "tools:layout=" for FragmentContainerView?

Tags: android, android-studio

In order to be able to see the content of a certain view inside a fragment when previewing a layout in Android Studio, it is possible to do [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#toolslayout):

```xml
<MainLayoutView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <fragment
        ...
        tools:layout="@layout/my_fragment_view"/>

</MainLayoutView>
```

However, if you switch from `fragment` to `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView`, this handy tool stops working and the fragment just appears blank on the preview screen.

Is there any way to show content inside a `FragmentContainerView` when previewing it in a layout in Android Studio?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I help myself by switching to <fragment> and then back again :)

Comment: Unfortunately, unless I have missed something, I don't think there is a solution yet.

Comment: Looks like this gets fixed in Android Studio 4.2 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159274992

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [comment by tir38](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59007007/is-there-an-equivalent-of-toolslayout-for-fragmentcontainerview#:%7E:text=tir38-,Sep%2016%2C%202020%20at%2019%3A49,-Add%20a%20comment) **this was fixed in later versions of Android Studio**, you can now use the tools:layout attribute in the FragmentContainerView. In cases where you are using [Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started),
if you define a startDestination for your [Navigation graph](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-design-graph)
which uses the tools:layout attribute, this will automatically be reflected in your FragmentContainerView

```html
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView 
    ...
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"/>
            
            
<navigation 
    ...
    app:startDestination="@id/someFragment">
    <fragment
        ...
        android:id="@+id/someFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_splash"/>
</navigation>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the preview was not working even after adding `tools:layout="@layout/...`. I also had to add `android:name="packageName + name of the fragment I wanted to show in preview"`.

So the final XML looked something like this:

```xml
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/someFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.example.packageName.FragmentName"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.sample.example.fragment.ButtonFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment"
    />
```

Even if tools:layout shows a red line,
(Of course, a namespace for tools must be defined.
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
),
If you write everything up to "@layout/fragment" in the back, you will see the xml preview.